# Make a delete function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried to implement a function that automatically does this:

```
del data['method_code']
del data['aqi']
del data['local_site_name']
del data['cbsa_name']
```

I have this function:

```
def del_data_func(data,columns):
  data[columns] =  data[columns].apply(lambda x: del(x))
  return data
del_list = data.columns[['method_code','aqi','local_site_name','cbsa_name']]
del_data_func (data, del_list)
```

How can i implement it in the right manner and avoid any errors like this one :

```
data[columns] =  data[columns].apply(lambda x: del(x))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `lambda` is requirement, otherwise one way is to `loop`:
If `df` is:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2     2
2     3     3     3     3     3
3     4     4     4     4     4
4     5     5     5     5     5
```

Then, function can be written as:

```
def del_data_func(data,columns):
    for column_name in columns: del data[column_name]
```

Now, calling the function:

```
del_list = ['col2', 'col4']
del_data_func (data, del_list) 
print(data)
```

Output: after `col2` and `col4` are removed:

```
   col1  col3  col5
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3
3     4     4     4
4     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not try this?

`data.drop(['method_code', 'aqi', 'local_site_name', 'cbsa_name'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

That list could be in fact any list as long as the elements in the list are valid column names from your dataframe.